# Are subjects joined by “or” singular or plural?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, compound-subjects

When the *or* between the two subjects is exclusive I think people generally use the singular form:

> I'm still not sure if pizza or curry **is** the best option.

But when considering a sentence with inclusive *or*:

> I'm waiting to see if Mike or John **join** the call

should it be *join* (plural) or *joins* (singular)?

Comment: Where both of the coordinates are singular and joined by "or", singular agreement is normal.

Comment: It might depend on the exact context. *Do you know if Alice or Bob **are** coming to the party?* implies speaker is looking to be told that *either, neither*, or *both* are coming, whereas *Do you know if Alice or Bob **is** coming to the party?* implies speaker expects to be told that *either* Alice or Bob is coming (he doesn't expect the answer to be *neither* or *both*).

Comment: I feel like *join* is more technically correct but I hear people say *joins* a lot in informal speech.

Comment: When we talk of singular agreement being normal, we are of course referring to the structure of the OP's particular examples.

Comment: @user178049 I don't understand your comment. The OP has to choose between singular ("joins") and plural ("join"). So what do you mean by "singular ... Join"?

Comment: @rjpond thank you for pointing that out. It was a typo and should have been "joins". I deleted my comment.